# React Native Realm Migration

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-migration

In React Native, where are you supposed to put the migration code or code to delete the realm database (ignoring migration) and for it to only run once?

I tried deleting the Realm database each time I am back on the Login screen. When I try to login, it is supposed to save the user info into Realm and then the app proceeds as normal. However this is not the case, it seems because Realm database was deleted, it has no where to save it. I would have thought that once I login, by saving the user info into Realm, it would initialize Realm and then save the user in Realm.

In debug mode, it seems even by deleting the Realm database, everything functions normally. Debug mode is a lot slower, so is there a timing issue somewhere?

Is there a method to initialize Realm?

Comment: Are you using Realm with sync (the Realm Mobile Platform)? Or is your user something that you keep track of yourself?
Normally, you would not delete your realm files all the time, unless you are using them for caching or something similar.

Comment: I'm just using the Realm javascript for React Native. My issue is that if the schema changes, how do you handle migration? Where exactly do you put the code for it? I don't always need to perform migration, deleting realm and re-initializing is sufficient but that doesn't seem to work. If the user downloads the app on the store, and then I update the schema for the next update, what would happen? Would the Realm database be removed after the re-install? If so, that would work. If it doesn't then it's going to be a problem.

Comment: Take a look at the [migrations](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#migrations) section of the documentation. Does that help you?

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to get the migration to work.

I have `realm.js` located in `/src` where I keep all my react files. When I need to use my realm I `import realm from 'path/to/realm.js';`
In `realm.js` I have my old schema and my new schema.

```
import Realm from 'realm';

const schema = {
    name: 'mySchema',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
    }
};

const schemaV1 = {
    name: 'mySchema',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        otherName: 'string',
    }
};
```

Note they have the same name. Then at the bottom of my `realm.js` where I used to have `export default new Realm({schema: [schema]});`

I now have this:

```
export default new Realm({
    schema: [schemaV1],
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {
        // only apply this change if upgrading to schemaVersion 1
        if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < 1) {
            const oldObjects = oldRealm.objects('schema');
            const newObjects = newRealm.objects('schema');

            // loop through all objects and set the name property in the new schema
            for (let i = 0; i < oldObjects.length; i++) {
                newObjects[i].otherName = 'otherName';
            }
        }
    },
});
```

If you don't need to migrate the data, you could just open the Realm with the new schema version and new schema and it should also work.

Comment: don't u get both oldRealm and newRealm empty?

Comment: I am getting oldRealm and newRealm empty

Answer (score 0):

If you have just added or removed fields of your schema, you can performe a empty migration. This is my realm.js file:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
//models
import Registros from '../models/registros';
import Local from '../models/local';

export default function getRealm() {

   return Realm.open({
      schema: [Registros, Local],
      schemaVersion: 1, //add a version number
      migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {

   },
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

simply add schemaVersion={2} to RealmProvider